# jQuery form plugin , how to submit only visible fields

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-forms-plugin

Using the jQuery [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), I  just want to submit the visible fields (not the hidden ones ) of the form.

HTML:

```
<div class="result"></div>
    <form id="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post"> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
        Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 

<div style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" value="" name="name_1" /> 
</div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 

    </form>
```

I cannot find a way to submit only the visible fields using any of the methods below:

**ajaxForm:**

```
// wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        });
```

**ajaxSubmit:**

```
$('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({
      target: '.result',   
      success: function(response) {
        alert("Thank you for your comment!");


      }
    });
```

There is another method `formSerialize` but found no way to use it with the 2 methods mentioned above (usable with `$.ajax` however).
How to submit only the visible fields using any of the two methods ?

Comment: Try something like `var queryString = $('#myForm input:visible,textarea:visible').fieldSerialize();`

Comment: @Regent, where to use that `queryString` variable ?

Comment: In [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `data` option. I didn't see the way to filter fields using jQuery Form Plugin, so I suggest to use simple `$.ajax()`, which will be called inside of `$('#myForm').sumbit(function() {});`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function() {
        var visibleData = $('#myForm input:visible,textarea:visible,select:visible').fieldSerialize();
        $.post(this.action, visibleData, function(result) {
            alert('Thank you for your comment!');    
        });
        // this is needed to prevent a non-ajax submit
        return false;
});
```

Comment: From OP : How to submit only the visible fields using **any of the two** methods

Comment: $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({
                target: '.result',
                data : $('#myForm input:visible,textarea:visible,select:visible').serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Thank you for your comment!");
                }
            });

Comment: Where is it mentioned in he form plugin site ?